# Play Framework 2.3 Plugin Could not be Loaded

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a custom plugin that I want to load when the Play application starts.

I have a play.plugins file in which I have the following line:

```
1000:my.package.MyPlugin
```

Since this is needed as soon as Akka plug in is loaded, I have given it 1000 as per the documentation here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaPlugins

When I run my app, I get to see the following error as soon as I try to hit a url that I have defined in my routes file:

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin[An exception occurred during Plugin [eon.optimizer.config.LifeCyclePlugin] initialization]
    at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:154) ~[play_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
```

Why is this error? What is that I'm doing wrong? I'm on Play Framework 2.3!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. The stacktrace gave me a hint! "exception during plugin initialization"

I had a val in my plugin which was the cause for this problem!

```
class MyPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {

  val myVal = SomeInitialization() // I had to change it to lazy val 
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? This in fact solved my problem!